# Unexpected Instance found for Alloy specification

Tags: modeling, alloy

I tried my first steps in modelling with **Alloy** and have come across a problem I cannot get my head around. I have the following spec:

```
module tour/AddressBook1

sig Name, Addr{}
sig Book {
    addr: Name->lone Addr
}

// operation: adds a (name, address) to the Book b, resulting in b'
pred add (b, b' : Book, n:Name, a:Addr) {
    b'.addr = b.addr + n->a
}

run add for 3 but 2 Book
```

So far nothing special. It is literally the example of the book 'Software abstraction' by Daniel Jackson.

It essentially models books, that have (name,address)-pairs associated with it. The add-predicate is supposed to grab a Book-instance b and create another Book-instance b' from it by adding (a potentially already existing) (name,address)-pair to it.

The first few examples found are easy and convincing but clicking through with the Next-button I end up with the following example (full view above, equivalent projection over books below)

[image: Found instance]

I see two books, the starting book Book0 with two pairs (Name0, Addr2) and (Name1, Addr1). From the annotions we can also see that the add operation is going to add the new duo (Name1, Addr2). When I now look at the result book Book1 I have 
{(Name0, Addr0),(Name1, Addr2)} instead of
{(Name0, Addr2),(Name1, Addr1),(Name1, Addr2)}

**Why is this considered a legal instance?**

(Alloy Analyzer 4.2, Build date 2012-09-25 15:54 EDT)

Comment: Thanks for adding in the pic, Peter Kriens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two confusing things here:

1. `Book0` does not take part in the operation. Instead `Book1` has the role of both `b0` and `b1`.
2. Adding `n->a` to a book does not assert that this is a new address. In the instance, `Book1` has this address before and after `add`.
   This is because the operation

   ```
   b'.addr = b.addr + n->a
   ```

   uses **set union**. Broken down to a simpler example:

   ```
   {1, 2} = {1} + {2}
   ```

   is true. But

   ```
   {1, 2} = {1, 2} + {2}
   ```

   is also true. So in the original example, there is nothing that excludes `n->a` from already being a part of `b.addr`. And the Alloy Analyzer simply generates all instances that are consistent with the given constraints.

You can improve this example by adding an assertion in `add`:

```
    b.addr[n] != a
```

Comment: Aah. That was indeed helpful! And I can see from the Book instance (top half of the pic) on which Book the predicate ran, right?
I played around running it with "but 1 Book" instead of "but 2 Book" and with your hint it all makes sense.
Your additional assertion for the add prevents pre-existing couples being added, right? If so, please briefly point it out and I will accept the answer!

Comment: Hm. No. Your additional assertion forces to be one book to be the 'before' state and the other the 'after' state but I don't get really why. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JanEckert: I have added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!